# Need help building a function in python to check a hand for pairs for the card game Go Fish

Tags: python

I am basically having a hard time figuring out how to set up a function to check a hand for pairs. I have the deck and cards set up to have the value and the suit so when I try to check the hand for pairs, even when there are pairs it does nothing. I know I need to slice the elements to get the value and then compare it to the other values in the hand, but I have been struggling with this for weeks and have made no progress whatsoever. This function is literally keeping me from turning in a few assignments so any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    def check_hand_pairs(player_hand):
        number = 0
        size = len(player_hand)
        while number <= size:
            (This is where I get confused and have tried many things)

    player_1_hand = ['2H', '4D', '2D', 'JD', 'KS', 'QS', 'AS']
    # (Basically, I need to compare the first character in each element
    # in the hand and then remove the pairs.)
```

Comment: care to show a little bit of code ?

Comment: sorry took so long, new to site so I had to figure a couple things out. After the while loop starts, I know I need to slice the card for the value since 2H won't match 2D, but cannot figure out how to do it and make it work.

Comment: that's fine no worries, can you show us what ```player_hand``` contains, like a sample of data.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I could thinks is making a function that returns True / False if the player has a pair. You can check if a player has a pair using `count` method.

```
def has_pair(hand):
    """
    Returns True if the hand has a pair, False otherwise.
    """
    for card in hand:
        if hand.count(card) == 2:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, problem is that the cards have a value and a suit. So, for example, a card would be 2H and you have to match values for a pair, so using the count method will not work. I tried something similar to this also but fell short of my goal.

Comment: Hmm I don't really understand what u are trying to achieve, to be honest I don't know the rules for Go Fish game, but maybe you could come with some examples of what input should take your function and what should be the output